# Measuring execution time for a Java doesn't work

Tags: java

I'm looking for measuring the execution time for a concret method in java. To be more precise I have implemented System.nanoTime() method rather than System.currentTimeMillis():

```
long startTime = System.nanoTime(); 
ServerRequestState state = (ServerRequestState) search.getGoalState();
long endTime = System.nanoTime();               
long elapsedTime = (endTime - startTime) / 1000000; // time in ms
```

But this has not worked for me, methods running between 30 and 40 seconds later, but the result of the variable elapsedTime says just 4 ms, 1 ms in some cases.

Any ideas why this is not working?

Answer (score 6):

1 millisecond == 1,000,000 nanoseconds.

I would recomment using Guava's [Stopwatch](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Stopwatch.html) to do what you're doing.

Comment: I have done an errata while copying the code. Thanks for the recommendation.

Comment: Then you're probably not measuring what is actually taking those 30 to 40 seconds. Replace the call to `search.getGoalState()` by `Thread.sleep(30000L)`, and you'll see that the elepsed time measure by your code is 30000 ms.